# Can you describe what is happening in this operation?

Tags: numpy, matrix

The below code is in a Python program I am using. Both T and P are 3,414024 matrices. I am unfamiliar with what the '.' is doing, and haven't been able to find a clear answer. Unfortunately, it is using way too much memory, so I am trying to find a more efficient way of coding the operation:

```
np.matrix(T+P).T*np.matrix(T+P)
```

It is part of this line:

```
N1 = (T+P)/np.sqrt(np.diag(np.matrix(T+P).T*np.matrix(T+P)))
```

Thank you for any advice that you can provide!

Comment: They are both 3x414024.

Comment: I realize the ‘.’ seems to be transposing the matrix. Is this correct? If so, I feel like there must be a less memory intensive way to do this.

Comment: `.T` is transposing.  In Numpy, transposing is done without actually moving the bytes around.  It just creates a new (small) array wrapper instance and twiddles some of the metadata, sharing the original underlying data array.  You should consider this to be a free operation, in both time and space.  The only major way to save memory is to assign T+P to a temporary so it's not computed twice and doesn't use 2 temporaries worth of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of obvious optimizations:

- compute `T+P` only once and store it in a temporary `TP`, say
- do not compute the full matrix `TP.T @ TP` only to
   immediately discard all but the diagonal---instead only
   compute the diagonal elements in the first place:
   `np.einsum('ij,ij->j', TP, TP)`

With your numbers, the second should cut both computation time and memory used by an utterly ridiculous factor of 10^4 - 10^5.

Besides:

- avoid the `matrix` class in favor of `array`

To summarize, use:

```
TP = T+P
N1 = TP/(np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->j', TP, TP)))
```

Comment: @kmario23 Since we keep the last dimension it works as is. (Now that I have added the missing closing parenthesis.)

Comment: This does the trick. It reduces processing times by about one-million fold and no longer kills memory. I'll be sure to get these changes to the author of the program. I am sure he will appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The below line:

```
np.matrix(T+P).T*np.matrix(T+P)
```

basically first does an element-wise addition (`T+P`) and then the result is transposed using `.T`. This is (matrix) multiplied with  a matrix resulting from (`np.matrix(T+P)`)

Below is a toy example:

```
In [14]: m
Out[14]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 5]])

In [15]: n
Out[15]: 
matrix([[10, 20, 30, 40],
        [11, 21, 31, 41]])

In [16]: m.T * n
Out[16]: 
matrix([[ 32,  62,  92, 122],
        [ 53, 103, 153, 203],
        [ 74, 144, 214, 284],
        [ 95, 185, 275, 365]])
```

Note that transposing m (i.e. `m.T`) is a **must** for the matrix multiplication (*`*`*) to work.

---

As you can see from the above example, the dimension of the resultant matrix comes from dimension of columns since dimensions on the rows cancel out (`4x2, 2x4` => `4x4`) Thus, since your matrices are very huge (`3x414024`), memory consumption is also huge.

---

After addition operation (`T+P`), the dimensions of the resultant matrix are the same (`3x414024`). And on transposing, this becomes (`414024x3`). This in turn on a matrix multiply with another (`3x414024`) matrix yields the result a matrix of dimension (`414024x414024`) which is definitely a huge matrix.